# What's wrong with my card shuffling code?

Tags: python

I wrote a program in Python3.3, that asks you how many cards you would like, and prints out these cards randomly from a deck. Also, you can't get the same card twice.

So I set the variable `y` to the number of cards you want. But I had a problem. If I tried to print 52 cards, it gave me below error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Users\Ali\Documents\Python\Suits2.py", line 28, in <module>  
     randomnumber = random.randint(0,52-t)  
   File "C:\Python33\lib\random.py", line 213, in randint  
     return self.randrange(a, b+1)  
   File "C:\Python33\lib\random.py", line 191, in randrange  
     raise ValueError("empty range for randrange() (%d,%d, %d)" % (istart, istop,   width))  
 ValueError: empty range for randrange() (0,0, 0)
```

What this error is and how to fix my code (below)?

Also, how I could easily shorten it (I'm not good at programming so nothing beyond what I know already (In the code pretty much)?

Code:

```
import random  
t = 1  
u = 0  
v = 0  
w = 0  
x = 0  
y = int(input("Please enter how many cards you want: "))  
z = y  
card = [""]  
card2 = [""]  
clubs = ["Clubs"]  
hearts = ["Hearts"]  
diamonds = ["Diamonds"]  
spades = ["Spades"]  
cards =["Ace","Two","Three","Four","Five","Six","Seven","Eight","Nine","Ten","Jack","Queen","King"]  
while w<52:  
    card.append("")  
    card2.append("")  
    w+=1  
while x<52:  
    card[x] = cards[u]+" of Clubs"  
    card[x+1] = cards[u]+" of Hearts"  
    card[x+2] = cards[u]+" of Diamonds"  
    card[x+3] = cards[u]+" of Spades"  
    x+=4  
    u+=1  
while z>=0:    
    randomnumber = random.randint(0,52-t)  
    card2[y-z] = card[randomnumber]  
    card.remove(card[randomnumber])  
    z-=1  
    t+=1  
while y>=1:  
    print(card2[y])  
    y-=1
```

Answer (score 0):

The error means your random.randint() is calling on a range where stop is < start. So if I say random.randint(3,1), it would throw this exception. Make sure your 52-t never goes below 0.

Extra tips on your coding style:
It is normal to include everything in a main() function like this:

```
def main():
    #Your code here
```

And then to call it like this:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Other recommendations:

- Make sure your variables are way more descriptive than just letters. It's way too hard for yourself and anyone else to read your code otherwise.
- I would use a dictionary to convert between numbers and words. I'm confused as to what you're doing with lists, but making one element lists for ease of list concatenation is probably not good practice.

I'll write up an improved version of this code as an example as soon as I have some time.

Here is my version that (I think) is more "pythonic":

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import random

def main():
    suits = ["Clubs", "Hearts", "Diamonds", "Spades"]
    ranks = ['Ace', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four', 'Five', 'Six', 'Seven', 'Eight', 'Nine', 'Ten', 'Jack', 'Queen', 'King']
    numberOfCardsToGenerate = int(input("Please enter how many cards you want: "))

    cards = []

    for suit in suits:
        for rank in ranks:
            cards.append(rank + " of " + suit)

    for i in range(numberOfCardsToGenerate):
        chosenCard = random.choice(cards)
        print(chosenCard)
        cards.remove(chosenCard)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Feel free to ask if any of this is unclear!

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure the range is always a valid one. Also, when you are printing the values you are printing 1 to 51, with the following code it prints from 0 to 51.

```
import random
t = 1
u = 0
v = 0
w = 0
x = 0
y = int(input("Please enter how many cards you want: "))
z = y
card = [""]
card2 = [""]
clubs = ["Clubs"]
hearts = ["Hearts"]
diamonds = ["Diamonds"]
spades = ["Spades"]
cards =["Ace","Two","Three","Four","Five","Six","Seven","Eight","Nine","Ten","Jack","Queen","King"]
while w<52:
    card.append("")
    card2.append("")
    w+=1
while x<52:
    card[x] = cards[u]+" of Clubs"
    card[x+1] = cards[u]+" of Hearts"
    card[x+2] = cards[u]+" of Diamonds"
    card[x+3] = cards[u]+" of Spades"
    x+=4
    u+=1

while z>0:
    randomnumber = random.randint(0,52-t)
    card2[y-z] = card[randomnumber]
    card.remove(card[randomnumber])
    z-=1
    t+=1
while y>=0:
    print(card2[y])
    y-=1
```

Instead of writing lots of stuffs, you can try this to append smartly:

```
    u = v = w = x = 0
```

Similarly,

```
    card2 = card = ["" for x in range(52)]
```

Some small suggestions, you can avoid extra lines when you can replace while loop with a for loop like this:

```
    for i in range(52):
            print(card2[i])
```